# VS2010, .Net 4, MVC3, Entity Framework 5 to VS2013, MVC4, EF6.1, .Net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

The app works fine right now. Wondering if I can derive any benefits by moving to Visual Studio 2013, ASP.NET MVC 4, Entity Framework 6.1, .Net 4.5. Before I put in efforts (which doesn't sounds like much), is there something in these new components to make things better and more efficient? Any cool features in ASP.NET MVC 4 or Entity Framework 6.1 or .Net 4.5 that can help make the code better?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking of upgrading then I believe you should pass MVC 4 and go to MVC 5, here you will get better:

- Routing, > attributed routing
- Identity model > 2.0
- Bundling and Minification
- OpenID and OAuth
- SimpleMemeberShipProvider and not DefaultMemberShipProvider

but moving all the way to MVC 6 is not recommended, since things have been completely re-designed in MVC 6 (ASP.NET vNext).

Comment: True. If doing the move, why not MVC5.  MVC 6, this is the first time I am hearing this.  When I go to Nuget, it only shows me MVC 5 when I search for MVC.

Comment: I understand MVC 6 as being ASP.NET vNEXT

Answer (score 0):

There are lot's of improvements I've found in those newer versions.

For MVC5: A more stable WebAPI (particularly for OData), better scaffolding, support for Bootstrap, Enum support in views.
For EF 6: Custom Code First Conventions, Interception / SQL Logging.

But your's is an existing application so in your case the thing that stands out to me is Async support which *may* give you scalability/performance improvements.

Comment: Async sounds interesting.  Looks like it is worth upgrading. Thanks.

Comment: Ran into one issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597847/mvc4-an-asynchronous-operation-cannot-be-started-at-this-time-code-works-fi