# MVC4- An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time --- code works fine on MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I converted a project from MVC3 to MVC4 and also from Entity Framework 5 to EF 6.1.  In the code there is a VBHTML page that has a code section "Using Html.BeginForm....  end using".  in this page, a user can select a file and click submit.  That calls a POST method in a controller.  The method in the controller uploads the selected file to Google drive using resumable uploader (aynchronous) of GData API.  ResumableUploader has to be used (GData API restrictions for uploading PDF and big files).  Now, this code has always worked in the past in MVC3.  As soon as the platform was changed to MVC4, started getting this exception:

An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>

```
at System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted() at Google.GData.Client.ResumableUpload.ResumableUploader.AsyncStarter
(AsyncResumableUploadData data, WorkerResumableUploadHandler workerDelegate, 
Object userData)
```

I did put @Page Async="true" in the VBHTML page, but that did not help.   I am 100% sure this is related to MVC4 and/or .Net 4.5 because no other change has been done in the code (other than moving to MVC4 and moving to .Net4.5).  I have two code branches now, one on MVC3 and one on MVC4.  When I compile MVC3 and copy the output DLL in the app, the above issue does not surface.  When I replace that DLL by MVC4 version, the above issue comes up.  How to handle this?

This is the code that causes this issue:

```
Dim auth As Authenticator = New AuthSubAuthenticator("MyToken", authFactory.Token)
Dim uploader As New ResumableUploader(10485760)
AddHandler uploader.AsyncOperationCompleted, AddressOf UploaderCompleted
uploader.InsertAsync(auth, file, New Object())
```

The trace shows that the exception was thrown from the last line (uploader.InsertAsync)

---

I understand there is a await method that I could use. Did not try, instead, changed `uploader.InsertAsync` to `uploader.Insert` and the code works ok.  But but the user has to wait until the upload is complete (for bigger files, for quite a while).

Answer (score 1):

> I am 100% sure this is related to MVC4 and/or .Net 4.5

Yes, this is a change in ASP.NET 4.5. However, it's important to note that the code was technically wrong before. ASP.NET 4.5 adds several safeguards to catch improper asynchronous usage. So, the MVC3 code was actually improper; it just wasn't getting caught and reported as such.

> changed uploader.InsertAsync to uploader.Insert and the code works ok. But but the user has to wait until the upload is complete (for bigger files, for quite a while).

This is the "proper" way to do it on ASP.NET (on a side note, using `await` would be more efficient than `Insert`). ASP.NET is not designed to do work without a user connection.

Consider, for example, what would happen if the upload errors out; there's no way to notify the user that the upload in fact did not complete. For that matter, there's no way to notify the user that the upload *did* complete. Also, ASP.NET may recycle your application, which can kill an in-progress upload. For these reasons, doing "fire and forget" work is not recommended on ASP.NET.

However, if you're willing to live with those limitations, I describe on my blog a variety of ways to do [fire and forget on ASP.NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html). Note that ASP.NET 4.5.2 added a built-in way to do this: `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.

Comment: All due respect, this doesn't appear to be the reason why they decided to make such a substantial change.  Programmers can take care of "what would happen if upload errors out" even when the program is running in the background.  A call back function can easily display a message on UI to notify the user something went wrong. There could be many other ways to notify users in case of an error.  If your theory were true, why is that .net does not force programmers to catch all errors and notify users.

Comment: I can easily catch all errors and just disregard them. Can .Net do anything about it?  Every time we upgrade from one version to another, we spend tens of hours on silly things like this. It is unfortunate that despite being in the market for so long, MS people hasn't learn how to write software.

Comment: So basically you are saying that use of threading is inherently wrong in .Net.  It is inherently wrong to launch a worker thread in .Net?  So basically Azure's worker role is inherently wrong because ultimately, those workers need to be triggered from something that a user may do.

Comment: The fact is that their own specification states that using Async =true in the page would take care of it.  But, how come it doesn't work?

Comment: @AllenKing: This isn't the *reason* they made the change; it's a side effect. The *reason* was `async`/`await` support; ASP.NET had to fix how it handled asynchronous code, and while they were in there, they put in these bug catchers. I'm not sure what you mean by "display a message on UI"; this is ASP.NET, and it raises an exception just like any other kind of improper usage (like an array index out of bounds); on your local machine, it will display the error details. Do not catch this error; it's indicative of a serious problem...

Comment: @AllenKing: There's nothing wrong with threading, but there is definitely something wrong with doing threading wrong. ASP.NET was not designed with application-level worker threads in mind, but it is technically possible to use them. Azure worker roles are completely different since they are not hosted in ASP.NET.